# Installing IntelliJ + Scala under Ubuntu

Tags: scala, ubuntu, intellij-idea

I am a bit confused right now. I have installed IntelliJ and the Scala SDK using the installation wizard provided by IntelliJ. I selected the latest version 2.11.8 but were not able to run it in the terminal.

After that I ran

```
sudo apt-get install scala
```

which is apparently version 2.9.2

```
scala -version
Scala code runner version 2.9.2 -- Copyright 2002-2011, LAMP/EPFL
```

It appears that I now have installed scala under

```
/home/<user>/.ivy2/cache
```

(which comes from IntelliJ and has version 2.11.8) and also

```
 whereis scala
 scala: /usr/bin/scala /usr/bin/X11/scala /usr/share/man/man1/scala.1.gz
```

which comes from the package manager and hast version 2.9.2.

How would I clean up this mess?

Comment: btw you can install scala in general for your console, but you can also added scala plugin that comes with intelliJ with out installing extra things, you can also have both. I am not very familier with ubuntu, but maybe try to uninstall and reinstall things again.

Answer (score 0):

This is not really a mess. It's perfectly possible to install a system-wide Scala and one based on your projects. The system-wide one really makes little sense except for you to run shell scripts using `scala script.scala`. You can also see that those Debian and Ubuntu packages are horribly outdated.

Since Scala is not an end-user application but a compiler or library required by specific project builds, one usually does not need and/or use a global installation. When you build a project using sbt or IntelliJ, your project can freely choose the Scala version it wants to use, whether that's 2.9.2, 2.10.x, 2.11.x or 2.12.0-Milestone... And therefore, these installations are all kept concurrently in a cache such as the Ivy cache you are seeing from IntelliJ/sbt.

```sh
$ ls -la ~/.ivy2/cache/org.scala-lang/scala-compiler/jars/
... scala-compiler-2.10.0.jar
... scala-compiler-2.10.2.jar
... scala-compiler-2.10.3.jar
... scala-compiler-2.10.4.jar
... scala-compiler-2.10.5.jar
... scala-compiler-2.10.6.jar
... scala-compiler-2.11.0.jar
... scala-compiler-2.11.1.jar
... scala-compiler-2.11.2.jar
... scala-compiler-2.11.5.jar
... scala-compiler-2.11.6.jar
... scala-compiler-2.11.7.jar
... scala-compiler-2.11.8.jar
... scala-compiler-2.12.0-M2.jar
... scala-compiler-2.12.0-M3.jar
... scala-compiler-2.7.3.jar
... scala-compiler-2.8.0.jar
... scala-compiler-2.8.2.jar
... scala-compiler-2.9.0.jar
... scala-compiler-2.9.2.jar
```

If you want a global installation because you want to run scripts without setting up a minimal sbt project, I recommend not to use apt (you can uninstall scala again) but simply download the latest version from http://scala-lang.org/download/ - I'm not aware of any .deb package depending on a .deb Scala installation.